# Breeze assumes EntityType is in same namespace as EntityContainer. Shouldn’t Breeze consider if the EntityType value is a qualified type name?

Tags: metadata, odata, breeze

- Library: BreezeJS 1.4.11 client-side library
- Data Service Adapter: webApiOdata
- Remote Service: Web API 2 Implementation of OData v3 without Breeze Controller

I’m working with metadata from a service provider that prefers to keep the EntityContainer in a separate namespace than the EntityTypes it contains. Here are a couple examples similar to our setup:

- Default configuration for Web API OData:
  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1579
- Northwind OData Sample Service:
  http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata

Consider Breeze’s CsdlMetadataParser.parse function:

```
var entityTypeName = parseTypeName(entitySet.entityType, schema).typeName;
```

This function assumes the EntityType has the same schema as the EntityContainer and does not consider the namespace provided in the EntityType attribute of the EntitySet.

A simple Breeze query for the top 10 "Categories" from the Northwind service causes the following error:

> Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Category:#ODataWebV3.Northwind.Model'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.

Shouldn’t Breeze consider if the EntityType value is a qualified type name and use that rather than assuming the container’s namespace?

**Update:** 
Breeze also assumes that the associations[] for a given navigation property are always in the same schema as the nav property. This causes the following error when attempting to import the metadata for associations in separate namespaces:

> "Cannot read property 'end' of null"

The error stems from Breeze's parseCsdlNavProperty and getAssociation functions:

```
function parseCsdlNavProperty(entityType, csdlProperty, schema) {
     var association = getAssociation(csdlProperty, schema);
```

Comment: So the manager has two namespaces?

Comment: The manager does have two namespaces, but the mappings inside of metadataStore._entityTypeResourceMap and metadataStore._resourceEntityTypeMap are incorrect. They point "Categories" to "Category:#ODataWebV3.Northwind.Model" instead of "Category:#NorthwindModel"

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this line in Breeze's CsdlMetadataParser.parse method:

```
var entityTypeName = parseTypeName(entitySet.entityType, schema).typeName;
```

With this:

```
var entityTypeName = parseTypeName(entitySet.entityType).typeName;
```

Resolves the issue and properly considers the namespace inside of the EntityType string. I'd like feedback from Ward or someone else on if this is the right strategy. Also, curious the reasoning behind passing the schema into parseTypeName method, in case removing it will break something else.

**Update:**
In order to support associations across schemas, I was able to resolve this issue by passing the schemas array all the way from CsdlMetadataParser.parse to getAssociation(). Once getAssociation has access to the schemas array, the following two updates resolve import by removing assumptions and looking at the namespace provided:

```
function getAssociation(csdlNavProperty, schemas) {
    var assocName = parseTypeName(csdlNavProperty.relationship).shortTypeName;
    var navSchema = __arrayFirst(schemas, function (sch) {
        return sch.namespace === parseTypeName(csdlNavProperty.relationship).namespace;
    });
    var assocs = navSchema.association;
    ...
```

---

```
function parseCsdlNavProperty(entityType, csdlProperty, schema, schemas) {
    var association = getAssociation(csdlProperty, schemas);
    var toEnd = __arrayFirst(association.end, function (assocEnd) {
        return assocEnd.role === csdlProperty.toRole;
    });

    var isScalar = toEnd.multiplicity !== "*";
    var dataType = parseTypeName(toEnd.type).typeName;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying "getQualifiedTypeName" in breeze.debug.js did the trick for me...

```
function getQualifiedTypeName(metadataStore, structTypeName, throwIfNotFound)
{
  structTypeName = (structTypeName || "") + "";
  var shortTypeName = (structTypeName.indexOf(':#') > -1) ?
    structTypeName.substring(0, structTypeName.indexOf(':#')) :
    structTypeName;
  var result = metadataStore._shortNameMap[shortTypeName];
  if (result) return result;
  if (isQualifiedTypeName(structTypeName)) return structTypeName;
  result = metadataStore._shortNameMap[structTypeName];
  ...
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of breeze is 1.5.3, and a lot of changes have been made since 1.4.11.

I would try that before 'fixing' the CsdlMetadataParser.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in Breeze 1.5.4.  I opened
https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/96
for it (seems like a bug more than a SO question?).

The workaround I found is to modify the

`if (schema) {`

line in `function parseTypeNameWithSchema(entityTypeName, schema)` ( breeze.debug.js line 7327) so that the function is:

`// schema is only needed for navProperty type name
  function parseTypeNameWithSchema(entityTypeName, schema) {
    var result = parseTypeName(entityTypeName);
    if (schema && !result.namespace) {
      var ns = getNamespaceFor(result.shortTypeName, schema);
      if (ns) {
        result = makeTypeHash(result.shortTypeName, ns);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }`

I believe this is the correct behavior, in that if the EntityType name is fully scoped, its namespace should be used; and if the EntityType is name only, the surrounding schema namespace should be used.